# play2 selectively override settings in application.conf for the run task

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-config

In production Play projects you can selectively override settings by adding another `application.conf` to the classpath. However this does not seem to work for the development run task. This would be useful so different developers test/work with different settings without affecting the versioned file.

In a non-Play scala project that uses typesefe-config you can do this by adding an additional application.conf in the sbt config:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Runtime ++= sys.env.get("CUSTOM_CONFIG").map(ec=>Attributed.blank(file(ec))).toSeq
```

This way each developer can have its own override. However the Play run task doesn't seem to honor this even thought according to `sbt inspect` it depends on the `runtime:unamanagedClasspath` setting.

You can of course provide a complete replacement for `application.conf` but not override just a few entries.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new config file: /my/local.conf

Within that file:

```
include "application.conf"

my.custom.setting="hello"
```

The first line references the application.conf within your classpath. The succeeding line adds/overrides settings.

You the start it with:

```
sbt -Dconfig.file=/my/local.conf ~run
```

Comment: All right. This should do it. Still weird that run does not honour the classpath.